# Unable to retrieve Facebook status messages that contain photos

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

When I make an FQL call to retrieve all the status messages of a Facebook Friend, any message that contains a photo is not sent.  I've added friends_photos to my list of permissions, but that doesn't help.  FYI, I'm using the FacebookClient from a C# application.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're after is the stuff that looks like a status update, just with a picture below it. That stuff ultimately ends up in the poster's "Wall Photos" album, so all you have to do is run another query looking something like this:

```
SELECT blah, blah, blah FROM photo WHERE album_object_id IN (SELECT object_id FROM album WHERE owner = ID_OF_FRIEND and name = "Wall Photos")
```

Then just mix those results with the status messages you already have.

(FYI, you'll also need something separate to deal with messages with attached links, which *also* have their own FQL table. Something like

```
SELECT blah, blah, blah FROM link WHERE owner = ID_OF_FRIEND
```

should do the trick.)